# How to convert array into JSON object in php

Tags: php, json

I want to convert my array value:

```
Array ( [page_1] => fifth [page_2] => first [page_3] => fourth [page_4] => third )
```

Into JSON format is given below

```
{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: did you have a try with json_encode ??

Comment: this is not json array format, this is string containing a byte-stream representation of value that can be stored anywhere. use `serialize($array)` to get this string format  and `unserialize($serialized_data)` to get array format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to serialize you array.

You need to use [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
<?php
$a = array (
        'page_1' => 'fifth',
        'page_2' => 'first',
        'page_3' => 'fourth',
        'page_4' => 'third');
echo serialize($a);
// Outputs: a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"fifth";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"third";}
?>
```

Comment: Just one more thing when i inserted into db the value is inserting not correct please tell me i am posting the query in the answer section.

Comment: what is the Data Type of your field in which you are inserting this data ?? @user2110253

Comment: its longtext  ,have you seen the output below which is inserting it add s:107:" on start and end }"

Answer (score 0):

$json = json_encode($array);

and otherwise

$array = json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 0):

When I insert the value in table it is inserting like

```
s:107:"a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}";
```

don't know why cause when i display it that is right but in table it is inserting something like above